# WPF: Filtering a dataGrid on the fly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

In my WPF `Window` I have a `DataGrid` control, with its `ItemsSource` bound to an ObservableCollection of items (let's say a simple object with a couple properties):

**XAML:** *(Removed some xmlns stuff for brevity)*

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyViewSource"
                              Source="{Binding MyItemList}"
                              Filter="MyItemList_Filter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <!-- Some Ioc stuff -->
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextFilter}" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewSource}}"
            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            HeadersVisibility="Column" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel (cs):**

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase // From Galasoft MVVM Light toolkit
{

    #region TextFilter Property
    public const string TextFilterPropertyName = "TextFilter";

    private string _TextFilter;

    public string TextFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _TextFilter;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_TextFilter == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _TextFilter = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(TextFilterPropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion // TextFilter Property

    #region MyItemList Property
    public const string MyItemListPropertyName = "MyItemList";

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _MyItemList;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItemList
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyItemList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_MyItemList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _MyItemList = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(MyItemListPropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion // MyItemList Property


}
```

Filter method, from **Window's code behind:**

```
private void MyItemList_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;
    var item = (Item)e.Item;
    // ...Simplified...
    e.Accepted = item.PropertyToCheck.Contains(vm.TextFilter);
}
```

Filtering is applied only when filling `MyItemList`: how can I make the `MyItemList_Filter` be called (and DataGrid items be shown/hidden accordingly) on "live" `TextFilter` change?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could (should) move the  filtering logic to the view model, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public const string TextFilterPropertyName = "TextFilter";

    private string _TextFilter;
    public string TextFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _TextFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_TextFilter == value)
                return;
            _TextFilter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(TextFilterPropertyName);
            Filter();
        }
    }

    public const string MyItemListPropertyName = "MyItemList";

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _MyItemList;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItemList
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyItemList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MyItemList == value)
                return;

            _MyItemList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyItemListPropertyName);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _filtered;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> FilteredList
    {
        get
        {
            return _filtered;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_filtered == value)
                return;

            _filtered = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredList");
        }
    }

    private void Filter()
    {
        _filtered.Clear();
        foreach(var item in _MyItemList)
        {
            if (item.PropertyToCheck.Contains(TextFilter))
                _filtered.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

That's where it belongs. Then you don't need to the CollectionViewSource:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredList}" ... />
```

Comment: That works, thank you. You said that filtering is a ViewModel-related stuff, but I hardly agree...

Comment: If you have any custom filtering logic this certainly goes in the view model if you intend to honour the MVVM pattern. An exception do this may be if you implement some very generic filter functionality that is for example part of the functionality of a control. But if you filter based on a value of a property in your view model, the filtering logic should be implemented in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

This can now be achieved using the NuGet package [DataGridExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/DataGridExtensions).

[image: Filtering a WPF datagrid using DataGridExtensions]