# Pointing a predicate to a getter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextBox` bound to `SearchText` which filters a `GridView`. I'm using MVVMLight and Fody.PropertyChanged.

The code below works. However, I feel like I should be able to point the `ExamsGridView.Filter` at my predicate in my constructor, leave `SearchText` as an auto-property (`{ get; set; }`), and have the predicate read from the "live" value of `SearchText` every time.

I've tried it with `SearchPredicate` (a function) and with `Pred` (a predicate object), and obviously these attempts have commented the last line of the `SearchText` setter and uncommented the last line of the constructor.

Now, as I write all that out I do realize that without a call from the setter, there's not really any concept of "every time".

Still feels like maybe it's possible in some way.

**Is there a way to filter based on my bound string property without actively resetting the filter/predicate on every text change?**

```cs
public class ExamsIndexViewModel : ViewModelWithExam
{
    private string searchText;
    public ObservableCollection<Exam> ExamsList { get; }

    public ICollectionView ExamsGridView { get; private set; }

    public string SearchText
    {
        get => searchText;
        set
        {
            searchText = value;
            ExamsGridView.Filter = SearchPredicate;
        }
    }

    public ExamsIndexViewModel()
    {
        // get the exams to display
        ExamsList = CoreMediator.GetExamsForPatient();

        ExamsGridView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ExamsList);
        // ExamsGridView.Filter = Pred;
    }

    private Predicate<object> Pred => exam => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || ((Exam)exam).Name.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;

    private bool SearchPredicate(object exam)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || ((Exam)exam).Name.IndexOf(SearchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;
    }
}
```

(xaml sample)

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ExamsGridView}"
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: If you set `ExamsGridView.Filter += SearchPredicate;` in the constructor, does that not behave like you want it? If not, please explain what happens.

Comment: No, when I try that (and remove the line from the `SearchText` setter) nothing happens.

Comment: Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809895/how-to-set-a-filter-for-a-datagrid-itemsource-via-mvvm), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925997/filtering-on-datagrid-with-wpf-mvvm-it-works-but-i-dont-know-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232238/wpf-filtering-a-datagrid-on-the-fly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `SearchPredicate` is invoked it reads current value of `SearchText`. But there has to be some code which calls that predicate, e.g via updating Filter property, or via [Refresh()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh):

```
public string SearchText
{
    get => searchText;
    set
    {
        searchText = value;
        ExamsGridView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

it will also help to add Delay to binding to reduce amount of filtering while typing:

```
TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Delay=250, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

if user types quickly (faster than 250 ms), SearchText won't be updated after each symbol - only after user has stopped

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds like what you're saying is, "No, there's no way to do it outside of the `SearchText` setter. Correct?

Comment: There is no way to make SearchText an auto-property and still have filtering. You need to trigger it from somewhere - setter is an appropriate place. There is Reactive UI framework - you can create a subscription to SearchText and invoke some acton on each change, but it will require change notification from SearchText - also from setter. I don' think there is a reason to complicate things here